# How can I make sure the return is an array?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using the COALESCE operator to make sure I return a consistent data set.

The query looks as follows

```
SELECT c.id, c.ItemLevel, c.ItemNo, bv.variantId, bv.variantDescription, c.DetailedData.locales[0].images ?? c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path AS images, c.PriceData.WhitePrice, c.PriceData.RedPrice, c.PriceData.DiscountPercentage, c.PriceData.TypeOfDiscount
FROM c
JOIN bv IN c.BasicData.base.sales.variants
WHERE c.brand = 'XXX'
AND c.Consumer = 'YYY'
AND bv.variantId = 'TTT'
AND c.Season = 'XXX'
```

My challenge is that `c.DetailedData.locales[0].images` is an array but `c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path` is not.

I need the `c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path` to be an array so that the JSON returned is consistent so I can loop the array in my mobile app directly.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may get your points.

For example, you have below 2 sample documents:

```
[
    {
        "DetailedData": {
            "locales": [
                {
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "image": "pic1"
                        },
                        {
                            "image": "pic2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "DetailedData": {},
        "BasicData": {
            "asset": {
                "assets": [
                    {
                        "locations": [
                            {
                                "path": "AAA"
                            },
                            {
                                "path": "BBB"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

If you execute your sql,you will get different format:

```
SELECT c.DetailedData.locales[0].images ?? c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path AS images
FROM c
```

[image]

You could add `[]` to reset the column,like:

```
SELECT c.DetailedData.locales[0].images ?? [{"image": c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path}] AS images
FROM c
```

Output:

[image]